# Where can I find Proguard rules in the AAR?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, aar

I'm trying to include proguard rules in the AAR of my library.

To my knowledge the `consumerProguardFiles` in the `buildTypes` of the `build.gradle` file should provide proguard rules in the aar.

```
buildTypes {
            debug {}
            release {
                consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to see the proguard rules of my library when I import it into an android application? 
Currently the aar only contains a classes.jar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consumer Proguard rules are added as file proguard.txt inside the aar file.

Comment: I checked the aar in the file system and found the proguard.txt there. Looks like Android Studio does not show the proguard.txt file in the Project view. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly AAR file contains:

```
/AndroidManifest.xml
/classes.jar
/res/
/R.txt
/public.txt
```

Additionally an AAR file may include one or more of the following optional entries:

```
/assets/
/libs/name.jar
/jni/abi_name/name.so (where abi_name is one of the Android supported ABIs)
/proguard.txt
/lint.jar
/api.jar
```

Excerpt from the official documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library